# At what point in the Strike Witches timeline does Brave Witches take place?

Tags: strike-witches, brave-witches

I recently finished the *Strike Witches* anime (Season 1, 2, *Operation Victory Arrow* OVAs and Movie) and am planning to continue watching up to *Brave Witches*. I want to preserve the continuity of the series as I am watching it.

In the first episode, Miyafuji Yoshika is seen in the company of Sakamoto Mio as seen in the newspaper clipping below:

[image: the newspaper clipping]

However, it seems that Miyafuji is still not that famous. I assume then that *the events of Brave Witches start in the middle of Strike Witches Season 1*.

Is my assumption correct? Where does *Brave Witches* take place in the whole timeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  To be specific, BW's episode 1 takes place around SW's episode 6, considering the time lag of news traveling at that period.  The creator Fumikane gave that tidbit of information through his [tweet](https://twitter.com/humikane/status/785527062555598848) (Japanese)

> で、1話。新聞に載っている坂本と宮藤。扶桑に情報が来るラグを考えると、ストライク1期の6話あたり、隊全員が一つのチームとして機能し始めたころ撮られたものでしょう。

Comment: Thanks! Can I request you to please quote the statement on twitter in your answer? I have also done some rough translation of Fumikane's statement here: `So, episode 1. Sakamoto and Miyafuji are on the newspaper. Considering the lag when information comes to Fusou, it occurred probably around the time the team[501st Joint Fighter Wing] started functioning as one, around Strike 1's episode 6.` You could also add it to your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding [Fumikane's tweet](https://twitter.com/humikane/status/785527062555598848) on [Jimmy's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/37466/2516), to be more exact, he says the picture was taken around episode 6, not that the episode of *Brave Witches* takes place around episode 6.

Due to mention of the liberation of Galia in *Brave Witches*, the series takes place after SW1 and after the manga *Strike Witches: The Sky That Connects Us*.

It's worth noting Hikari is not seen among the 502nd at the start of the SW Movie, so we'll have to see what that ultimately means.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather possible that it only happened during the end of S1, as BW was set during October and in episode 7, it was revealed that it was already December during that period.

Considering that Yoshika's and Mio's trip to Britannia took only 2 months (taking the southern route of Yokosuka-Macau-Malacca-India-Egypt-Cape-Town-Pas de Calais-Dover), it's possible that BW happened during August as the news of Mio's arrival just reached them and after the approval of Hikari being sent to Orrusia, she has to train more in their school and she was taken to Orussia the same time that the Shokaku was on a voyage to Novo-Khmolgory. There was a 2-month break in between EP 1 and EP 2 as EP 2 started with the news of Gallia's Liberation.